# WPGrabber для Wordpress. Нужна помощь с настройкой парсинга

Tags: wordpress, регулярные-выражения, парсер, wordpress-плагины, pcre

Я пытаюсь настроить парсинг с раздела форума http://promalp.ru/viewforum.php?f=12

Ссылки на топики в html указаны как: .viewtopic.php?f=12&t=46263

Как спарсить?

```html
viewtopic\.php\?f=12&t=\d{5,}
```

не дает результата. Спасибо.

Comment: Дополню. Ссылки видимо парсятся, но по ним обхода не происходит из-за точки в начале. Как ее исключить? Помогите девушке )

Answer (score 0):

Решила. В HTML коде после & стоит &amp^ вот и всё